# Stormpath ID into MongoDB as the ID

Tags: reactjs, stormpath

I am currently working in React (two weeks in), mongodDB and Stormpath (for login).  I would like to grab the stormpath ID and override my mongoDB ID.

Answer (score 0):

All Stormpath Accounts are identified by their HREF, e.g. https://api.stormpath.com/v1/accounts/UUID

Simply grab that UUID, and use that as the foreign key to relate your two databases together :)

More questions?  Chat with team [Stormpath](https://stormpath.com) on our [Slack Channel](https://talkstormpath.slack.com)